# Automatic URL parser is wrong (discarding character after URL)

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

When using the part `for https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/330357/272354:` in a question, the trailing colon is discarded.
IMHO it should be obvious that the colon cannot be part of the URL (link), so it should follow the encoded URL link text instead (or at least be part of the URL link text).

This is how that code snippet renders:

for [Error "UNIQUE constraint failed" with composite primary key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/330357/272354):

Comment: That seems to render fine in the question itself. It _only_ seems to break in the editing [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wnAJ.png).

Comment: Related, but somewhat orthogonal to your request– you can always wrap bare URLs in angled brackets to explicitly tell the formatter where the URL begins & ends (`<https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/330357/272354>`). This doesn't interfere with the magic that replaces bare Stack post URLs with the question title, either.

Comment: @Cerbrus Right, I realized during preview, assuming the final rendering would be the same.

Comment: @zcoop98 That's why I titled it "*Automatic* URL parser"; links marked manually probably all work correctly.

Comment: Cue bug reports about bare links to <https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror> not working.